# Why contains can't select rows contains specified string?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, contains

```
>>> y
1    2002-12-31
2    2003-12-31
3    2004-03-31
4    2004-06-30
Name: report_date, dtype: object
```

I want to extract rows which contain `12-31` .

```
>>> y.str.contains('12-31')
>>> y.str.contains('\.+12-31')
>>> y.str.contains('2002-12-31')
```

All the three expressions get same output:

```
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
Name: report_date, dtype: float64
```

How can i extract rows which contain string  `12-31`?
My desired output:

```
1   True
2   True
3   NaN
4   NaN
```

Comment: bdw, when working with dates, it is best to use the datetime accessors :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe in column are dates, so convert it to strings before:

```
m = y.astype(str).str.contains('12-31')
print (m)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: report_date, dtype: bool
```

Comment: @anky_91 - hmmm, maybe depends of pandas versions

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps work with datetimes and check the month and day fields:

```
df['report_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.report_date)

df[df.report_date.dt.month.eq(12) & df.report_date.dt.day.eq(31)]

report_date
1  2002-12-31
2  2003-12-31
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do

```
y.dt.strftime('%m-%d')=='12-31'
```